Cognito Provide Client Secret When Creating App
I am using CloudFormation to create a confidential app client for my cognito user pool.
My cloudformation resource looks like this:
AppClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
        ClientName: app-client
        UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoInfrastructureUserPool
        EnableTokenRevocation: false
        AccessTokenValidity: !Ref UserPoolAccessTokenValidity
        IdTokenValidity: !Ref UserPoolIdTokenValidity
        RefreshTokenValidity: !Ref UserPoolRefreshTokenValidity
        TokenValidityUnits:
            AccessToken: "hours"
            RefreshToken: "hours"
            IdToken: "hours"
        SupportedIdentityProviders:
            - COGNITO
        CallbackURLs: !Split [",", !Ref UserPoolCallbackUrls]
        LogoutURLs: !If
            - HasLogoutUrls
            - !Split [ ",", !Ref UserPoolLogoutUrls ]
            - !Ref AWS::NoValue
        AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true
        AllowedOAuthFlows:
            - code
            - implicit
        AllowedOAuthScopes:
            - phone
            - email
            - openid
            - profile
            - aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
        ExplicitAuthFlows:
            - ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH
            - ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
            - ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
        PreventUserExistenceErrors: ENABLED
        ReadAttributes:
            - address
            - birthdate
        WriteAttributes:
            - address
            - birthdate
        GenerateSecret: true

Instead of cognito generating the client_secret, I'd like to use a client secret that I generate. Is it possible to do so?
Also, is it possible to limit the access to the client secret for a limited set of aws users with a certain role.

What do you mean by "limit the access to the client secret"? End users (aka. Resource Owners in OAUTH jargon) should never have access to the secret.
Also, why would you want to set your own secret? Secret's should be as long as and complicated as possible; allowing the creation of arbitrary secrets would be lowering the security standards of the protocol.

I do not intend to expose the client secret to any end user. As per my understanding, any aws user with access to app client can see the client secret. I am wondering if I can provide two levels of access to any non-sensitive data of app client and client secret.

Pretty sure it isn't because when creating an app client in the console you can only select client secret or no secret. If you were to generate your own that would require capability of AWS or your app client trusting your code which isn't as secure.
I don't think it is possible to limir certain users access to the secret the best approach would be to have an app client with a secret and one with no secret I am pretty sure a cognito pool can use 2 app clients.

Thanks, by limiting access I meant having a seperate policy to secure the client secret. I do not intend to expose the client secret to any end user. As per my understanding, any aws user with access to app client can see the client secret. I am wondering if I can provide two levels of access to any non-sensitive data of app client and client secret.
